How to grant permission to open PRs on Bitbucket?
How do I grant appropriately-scoped permission for an automated process (like Renovate Bot) to propose new Pull Requests to a group of source code repositories hosted in Atlassian Bitbucket (which is a competitor to GitHub)?

In the Bitbucket security model, the resources include workspaces (organisations), projects (org sub-units), git repos, branches, PRs and comments. The principals include users, groups, user's apps, tokens (belonging to either repos, projects or workspaces), and add-ons (Atlassian Forge apps, Atlassian Connect apps, etc). However, the security controls are rather ad hoc: it isn't possible to grant permission for a principal to open a new PR without also granting permission for it to rewrite the entire commit history, except if you then configure branch protections to explicitly deny certain changes in the commit tree (or associated markers), although such controls can only refer to some principals and not others.. (Note there are proposals to broaden some of these controls, but on the other hand, several of the existing controls and protections are exclusive to "premium" subscriptions.) So some options are:
Use a token
Tokens can be created belonging either to an individual repo or to a collection of repos (in the organisation hierarchy).
For operating on multiple repos it is convenient to define a token at the collective level (rather than managing many individual tokens), but this obviously broadens the scope (if there are also additional repos gathered under the same level). There is facility to also apply branch protections at the collective level, but this requires care to ensure the branches selected for protection are applicable for every repo. (This can involve ensuring each repo uses the same branch names, or alternatively, ensuring each repo has a main branch configured. Note the "main branch" in Bitbucket settings is not necessarily the branch labelled main.)
However, since branch protections cannot refer specifically to a token, it isn't immediately obvious whether or not the token will be exempted if branch protections are enabled.
Use a wheel user-account
The other obvious approach is to use an "app password" associated to a particularly ("wheel") user. This lets a user delegate a subset of their permissions for use by the automated process. The access can be further narrowed by limiting what access that user has (which is more flexible than just the controls available for tokens).
The inconvenience is that a user account (with a real email address etc) is necessary for this purpose. This may involve extra management layers.
Note the app password is used in conjunction with the username (not the email address or fullname), although the username is not prominently visible to admins.
Use an OAuth app
There appears to be some facility for OIDC style access, whereby Bitbucket is configured to trust an external agent and that agent obtains a temporary token for use by the automated process. This seems like a potential advantage in that the automated process does not need access to long-lived credentials, but more complex to orchestrate. The implementation has various proprietary flavours e.g. Atlassian Forge apps, Atlassian Connect apps, etc.
